# I can print the values received from promise but cannot print its array.length

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[response screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gv66.png)
I receive an array of values from JavaScript promise. When I console.log, I can print it's value. But cannot print its array.length. please see te comments in getImageUrl() method

```
    public saveImages() {        
        for (let img of this.multipleImages) {
            if (img.file) {
                this.promise = this.FileUploadService.
                    addFile(img.file, img.randomName);
                this.promise.then(result => { 
                    this.setImageUrl(result);
                });
            }                     
        }
    }
    setImageUrl(result) {
        this.imageUrl.push(result);
    }
    getImageUrl() {
        console.log(this.imageUrl.length, // length is always 0
            this.imageUrl[0], //undefined
            this.imageUrl); // has  value (result from promise)
    }
    ngOninit() {
        this.saveImages();//saves the image and calls the setImageUrl method.
        this.getImageUrl();
    }
```

when this.getImageUrl() is called, you can see what is print and what is not in the console.log of getImageUrl() method.

Comment: When you console.log `this.imageUrl` what exactly do you see?

Comment: list of image urls in array.

Comment: i get the response . this isnt dupe.

Comment: if someone cant answer don't downvote pls.

Comment: could you please update the question with your `response.` . Also, what would happen if you call `this.getImageUrl()` after your `for` loop.

Comment: ``this.getImageUrl()`` is being executed before ``this.setImageUrl()`` .So call your ``this.getImageUrl()`` inside your promise block .

Comment: and this is because of the `asynchronous`  nature. That is why it was a possible dup.

Comment: Is this.imageUrl  an object or array or string? if this.imageUrl is string or array then you will be able to print length. You can not find length property in an object.

Comment: It is an array of string.  In the console I can see its length.

Comment: Your async operations (promises in `saveImages`) will be executed after your sync operations (`getImageUrl`). CruelEngine is correct. This is a duplicate

Comment: The screenshot of response is attached in the post.

Comment: The reason why your array is printed is that console.log will print the objects latest value to the console (object mutation). You shouldn't debug your code with console.logs, use breakpoints. Then you will see that the value is actually undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remove the `for` loop & skip overwriting your `this.promise` instance every iteration in that loop.

So, something like this:

```
const saveImages = () => Promise.all(this.multipleImages
  .map(img => img && img.file ? this
    .FileUploadService.addFile(img.file, img.randomName)
    .then(this.setImageUrl.bind(this)) : null
  ))

 // Then use with:
 saveImages()
   .then(() => this.getImageUrl())
```

Btw, here's where I'm working on these Promise ideas: https://github.com/justsml/escape-from-callback-mountain/

Comment: thanks and pls upvote the question.

Comment: Done.
If it worked pls upvote my answer :)

Comment: Done.  I already found my answer. I still appreciate you  for figuring out the problem.

Comment: in your answer you used map to call the function addFile, how do i pass the argument img.file only if it is not null?

Comment: Hey @kaws I updated my code snippet to return null if `img.file` is null. I added a little boolean expression after the `.map` and before `this.FileService...`. Don't forget the trailing `: null` after the `.then` bit.